# Adding icons to navigation bar in xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add icon to the navigation bar present in my xcode project.Can anyone guide me through any method to do so and also i want to do it programmatically.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;


UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@name.jpg"];
image=[[UIImageview alloc]initWithImage:image1];

image.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,400);
navigationbar.titleview=image;
```

EDIT:
image to the right side:

```
UIButton* fakeButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *fakeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fakeButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = fakeButtonItem;
[fakeButtonItem release];
[fakeButton release];
```

source:[pevious so questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844416/how-to-display-an-image-in-the-navigation-bar-of-an-iphone-application)

Comment: i want to align this image to right side ?how to execute that ,is there any alignment property available

Comment: now when i chenge the orientation of my ipad then icon is not displaye accoridngly what to do for this i used [image setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];but of no use

Answer (score 2):

Check below SO post.

[how to display an image in the navigation bar of an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844416/how-to-display-an-image-in-the-navigation-bar-of-an-iphone-application)

[adding icon between back button & title of navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323934/adding-icon-between-back-button-title-of-navigation-bar)

[Are there free iPhone navigation bar icon sets available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813096/are-there-free-iphone-navigation-bar-icon-sets-available)